# Is it necessary to use xlib's "XAllocSizeHints()"?

Tags: c, x11, xlib, hints

Xlib has a function called `XAllocSizeHints` to allocate a `XSizeHints` structure on the heap and set it to zero.

```
XSizeHints *sizehints;
sizehints=XAllocSizeHints();
```

However, is it necessary to always use this function? Or can I do this:

```
XSizeHints sizehints;
memset(&sizehints, 0, sizeof(XSizeHints));
```

I would like to know if it is possible to avoid `XAllocWMHints` and `XAllocClassHint` too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's fine to stack allocate these (as long as you don't keep them around after the current
function returns of course). There's no magic in those alloc functions. In fact most code probably does allocate them on the stack.

Comment: This is what I wanted to know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually better to use memset way, because if you call XAllocSizeHints() then you need to explicitly free memory with XFree().